# Python Discord Bot, Modul not found error

Tags: python, discord.py, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to create a discord bot, but i have basic problem...
I have this on start of code:

```
import discord.py
from discord.ext import commands
```

Im gettin that error:

> > PS C:\Users\trnka> & "C:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/python.exe" c:/Python_projects/Discord_Bots/RCN_bot/RCN.py Traceback (most recent
> > call last):   File "c:\Python_projects\Discord_Bots\RCN_bot\RCN.py",
> > line 1, in 
> > import discord.py ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

But I have installed everything from [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py), as instalation manual said.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Im using VS Code

Comment: Did you use a virtualenv? I think this tutorial desribes it better: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#virtual-environments

Comment: I've tried now, still `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'`

Comment: When you are in your virtualenv and its activated, can you do `pip list` and check if it is installed correctly? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/

Comment: when i write `py -m pip list`, I've got list with `discord.py           1.7.3` inside... so I think yes, it's installed correctly...

Comment: which python version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before:

```
import discord
```

After:

```
import discord.abc
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import discord
```

and not `discord.py`

**EDIT:** checking the repository page https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py supported versions are: 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8, maybe you need to try on those versions.

Comment: still, same error

Comment: updated the answer, please check it if works.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the program **outside VSCode** e.g. with the Python Program (so `python.exe` which you hopefully installed (standard is `C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/PythonVERSION/`)) or PyCharm as VSCode has their own library folder which seems to not include discor.py